# Converting between coordinate systems causing rotation/gimbal issues! Need assistance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinate-systems, rotational-matrices

I am trying to write a .bvh animation exporter for c# and am using this [export_bvh.py](https://github.com/sftd/blender-addons/blob/master/io_anim_bvh/export_bvh.py) script from Blender as an example to copy.

My Unity exporter script basically stores the bone's rotations every frame when the scene is active. After the scene stops it then saves that list of euler rotations to the .bvh file.

I have managed to get the header part of the file looking ok, but I am now having trouble calculating the angles for the bones.

From my understanding, they are the compound angles by multiplying the parent's global transform matrix by the child's transform matrix and a rest position matrix. But the details are not very clear to me.

So I have done my best to examine and copy the way the matrices are multiplied in the export_bvh.py script, and even though I feel I have made some progress, I still face an issue which has been present from the very start, after importing my recorded animations, the rotations are sometimes way off and sometimes not. Which I believe (but am not certain) is due to Blender being right-handed and Unity being left-handed coordinate systems.

For example, when I start the Unity scene and begin to record the animation, I then move some of the bones in my armature (which gets recorded), then after saving the animation I go to try importing the .bvh into Blender. After inspecting the animation I notice that when a bone was rotated along multiple axes it will have strange results in the animation and some of the rotations either snap around or appear to wobble violently. But usually when rotating along a single axes it appears to move in the correct direction.

I have created this video which explains the issue better and shows some examples:
[[image: Video thumbnail]

**MORE DETAILS** on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywpuyim3m6Q)

Here is the complete script for this project:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleBVH5 : MonoBehaviour {

    string bvhOutput;
    public string savePath = "C:\\animations\\animation.bvh";
    public int fps = 60;

    Quaternion rootRotationOffset;

    //ARMATURE BONES SECTION
    public Transform hip;
    public Transform spine;
    public Transform chest;

    public Transform shoulderR;
    public Transform upper_armR;

    public class DecoratedBone {
        public Transform bone;
        public DecoratedBone parent; // decorated bone parent, set in a later loop
        public Vector3 rest_bone_head; // blender armature bone head position
        public Matrix4x4 rest_arm_mat; // blender rest matrix (armature space)
        public Matrix4x4 rest_arm_imat; // rest_arm_mat inverted
    }
    List<DecoratedBone> dBones;

    //INITIALIZATION SECTION
    void OnEnable () {
        dBones = new List<DecoratedBone> ();
        rootRotationOffset = hip.rotation;

        int level = 0;

        bvhOutput = "HIERARCHY\n";
        bvhOutput += "ROOT hip\n";

        var dBone = new DecoratedBone ();
        dBone.bone = hip;
        dBone.rest_bone_head = hip.position;

        var rest_arm_mat = GetMatrix (dBone, rootRotationOffset);

        dBone.rest_arm_mat = rest_arm_mat;
        dBone.rest_arm_imat = rest_arm_mat.inverse;

        dBones.Add (dBone);

        bvhOutput += "{\n";
        var offset = hip.position;
        bvhOutput += "\tOFFSET " + offset.x.ToString("F6") + " " + (-offset).z.ToString("F6") + " " + offset.y.ToString("F6") + "\n";
        bvhOutput += "\tCHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation\n";

        var spineBone = InsertHierarchy (ref level, "spine", spine, dBone);
        InsertHierarchy (ref level, "chest", chest, spineBone);
        AscendLevel (ref level, chest, chest.GetChild (0), 1);
        var shoulderRBone = InsertHierarchy (ref level, "shoulder.R", shoulderR, spineBone);
        InsertHierarchy (ref level, "upper_arm.R", upper_armR, shoulderRBone);
        AscendLevel (ref level, upper_armR, upper_armR.GetChild (0));

        bvhOutput += "}\n";

        bvhOutput += "MOTION\n";
        bvhOutput += "Frames: 1\n";
        bvhOutput += "Frame Time:\t" + (1.0f / fps).ToString("F6") + "\n";

        StartCoroutine (RecordRoutine ()); // Finished building header info, Begin recording keyframes
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, bvhOutput);
        print ("SAVED FILE!!!");
    }

    // HEADER SECTION HELPERS
    DecoratedBone InsertHierarchy(ref int level, string name, Transform bone, DecoratedBone parent) {
        /* Creats hierarchy header info for bones with parents */
        string tabs = GetLevelTabs(level);
        bvhOutput += tabs + "JOINT "+name+"\n";
        bvhOutput += tabs + "{\n";
            var dBone = new DecoratedBone ();
            dBone.bone = bone;
            dBone.parent = parent;

            dBone.rest_bone_head = bone.position;
            var rest_arm_mat = GetMatrix (dBone, rootRotationOffset);

            dBone.rest_arm_mat = rest_arm_mat;
            dBone.rest_arm_imat = rest_arm_mat.inverse;
            dBones.Add (dBone); // Add bone to the list of bones (in the order it was created in the hiereachy/header).

            var offset = bone.position - parent.bone.position;
            bvhOutput += tabs + "\tOFFSET " + offset.x.ToString("F6") + " " + (-offset).z.ToString("F6") + " " + offset.y.ToString("F6") + "\n";
            bvhOutput += tabs + "\tCHANNELS 3 Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation\n";
        level++; // Increase the level in the hierarchy (increases depth in .bvh file and ensures curly braces will be added properly)

        Debug.DrawLine (parent.bone.position, bone.position, Color.cyan, 10.0f); // Outline the skeleton in the viewport for debugging
        return dBone;
    }

    string GetLevelTabs(int level) {
        string tabs = "";
        for (int lev = 0; lev <= level; lev++) {
            tabs += "\t";
        }
        return tabs;
    }

    void EndSite(int level, Transform bone, Transform endEffector) {
        string tabs = GetLevelTabs(level);
        bvhOutput += tabs + "End Site\n";
        bvhOutput += tabs + "{\n";
        var offset = endEffector.position - bone.position;
        bvhOutput += tabs + "\tOFFSET " + offset.x.ToString("F6") + " " + (-offset).z.ToString("F6") + " " + offset.y.ToString("F6") + "\n"; // 1 0 0\n";
        bvhOutput += tabs + "}\n";

        Debug.DrawRay (bone.position, offset, Color.cyan, 10.0f);
    }

    void AscendLevel (ref int level, Transform bone, Transform endEffector, int stopLevel = 0) {
        EndSite (level, bone, endEffector);

        for (int lev = level; lev > stopLevel; lev--) {
            for (int tab = 0; tab < lev; tab++) {
                bvhOutput += "\t";
            }
            bvhOutput += "}\n";
        }
        level = stopLevel;
    }


    //RECORDED MOTION SECTION
    IEnumerator RecordRoutine () {
        /*A simplified re-write of Blender's export_bvh.py script https://github.com/sftd/blender-addons/blob/master/io_anim_bvh/export_bvh.py*/
        string line; // The string used to build each line of data.
        float time = Time.time;
        float interval = 1.0f / fps; // The record frame interval.
        while (isActiveAndEnabled) { // Runs while the scene is actively running.
            yield return new WaitUntil (() => (Time.time - time) >= interval); // Wait for desired time interval.
            time = Time.time; // Reset the timer.
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame (); // Wait for all transforms to be updated.

            line = ""; // Clear the line data and prepare for next line of data.

            //First do calculations for the root (hip) bone.
            var p = dBones[0].rest_bone_head;
            var trans = Matrix4x4.Translate (p);
            var itrans = Matrix4x4.Translate (-p);

            var pose_mat = GetMatrix(dBones [0], rootRotationOffset);
            var rest_arm_imat = dBones [0].rest_arm_imat;

            var mat_final = pose_mat * rest_arm_imat;
            mat_final = itrans * mat_final * trans;

            var loc = mat_final.GetPosition () ;
            var rot = mat_final.GetRotation ().eulerAngles;
            line += // Add root's (hip bone) data to the line of data.
                (-loc.x).ToString("F6") + " " + //Output location of root bone
                (-loc.z).ToString("F6") + " " +
                (loc.y).ToString("F6") + " " +

                (rot.x).ToString("F6") + " " + //Output rotation of root bone
                (rot.z).ToString("F6") + " " +
                (-rot.y).ToString("F6") + " ";      

            // Now do calculations for each child bone
            for (int i = 1; i < dBones.Count; i++) { 

                p = dBones [i].rest_bone_head;
                trans = Matrix4x4.Translate (p);
                itrans = Matrix4x4.Translate (-p);

                mat_final = 
                    dBones [i].parent.rest_arm_mat * GetMatrix(dBones [i].parent).inverse *
                    GetMatrix(dBones [i]) * dBones [i].rest_arm_imat;
                mat_final = itrans * mat_final * trans;

                //loc = mat_final.GetPosition () + (trackedObjects [i].rest_bone_head - trackedObjects [i].parent.rest_bone_head); //Position is not required for non-root bones
                rot = mat_final.GetRotation ().eulerAngles;

                line += // Add children's data to the line of data.
                    (rot.x).ToString("F6") + " " + //Output rotation of child bone
                    (rot.z).ToString("F6") + " " +
                    (-rot.y).ToString("F6") + " ";
            }
            line += "\n"; // Done adding line.

            if (Application.isPlaying) {
                bvhOutput += line; // Add the data to the file's contents only if the scene is actively running.
            }

        }
    }

    Matrix4x4 GetMatrix (DecoratedBone dBone, Quaternion offsetRotation = default(Quaternion)) {
        //return trackedObject.obj.localToWorldMatrix;
        return Matrix4x4.TRS(
            dBone.bone.position,
            offsetRotation.Equals(default(Quaternion)) ? dBone.bone.rotation : dBone.bone.rotation * offsetRotation, //the offsetRotation (aka hip.rotation) should be applied to all bones with parents.
            Vector3.one
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: It sounds like the logic for only one axis is messed up, and it's most likely the Y axis. Try exporting 3 different times, each rotating on a different axis (only moving one axis per export) and see if one of the imports are messed up.

Comment: Probably should've added this to the first video: https://youtu.be/-Y3XfWx1WVI - I did do a test where I rotated bones along x then y then z all in clockwise directions, and then checked it in Blender and they all seemed ok.

Comment: It looks like the only axis that isn't compensating for "full circles", otherwise "0" or "-360" values, is the Y axis. This may have to do with taking the negative value of Y, although I am not sure. I'm curious as to what the output file is "recording". Try sticking a Debug.Log in there and seeing what Y comes out to be, or manually looking through the value file produced. Also wondering if rotating in multiple axis works if you only rotate on X and Z, excluding Y. Also, by Y, I mean BLENDERS Y axis... This could get confusing fast...

Comment: Not sure if this could be useful but here's (yet another) video of a side-by-side comparison of some compound rotations between Unity and Blender: https://youtu.be/bLHHd6oWfG0